# Show button in table based on other cells

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following code

```
<tbody *ngIf="packages">
              <tr *ngFor="let package of packages">
                <td class='checkbox'>
                  <label class="css-control css-control-primary css-checkbox table-select">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="css-control-input" (click)="selectPackage(package.name)"
                      [checked]="isSelected(package.name)">
                    <span class="css-control-indicator"></span>
                  </label>
                </td>
                <td> {{package.name}}</td>
                <td> {{package.version}}</td>
                <td> {{getNewMajorVersion(package.version)}}</td>
 <!-- <td (click)="createNewMajorVersion(package.name, package.version)"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></td> -->
 <!-- <td><button ng-show = "{{(package.name).includes('_v')">UPGRADE</button></td> -->
      <td> {{(package.name).includes('_v') ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Based on my first column package.name I would like to show a **button** in the last column. The name has to include **a version number (_v[0-9])**. The purpose is to click the button and upgrade the name.

I'm able to show YES or NO depending on the first column, but showing a button just doesn't want to work. Like u can see in the code I commented out I didn't found a good solution.

The following line `<td><button ng-show = "{{(package.name).includes('_v')">UPGRADE</button></td>` also shows the button on every row, and not only where he finds `"_v"`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ng-show` use `[style.display]`

```
<td><button [style.display] = "package.name.includes('_v') ? 'block' : 'none'" >UPGRADE</button></td>
```

or you can try [hidden]

```
<td><button [hidden] = "!package.name.includes('_v')" >UPGRADE</button></td>
```

add `[hidden] { display: none !important;}` in css